# Hide IF Item Type = Inventory Item

Tags: html, sql, freemarker, netsuite

I'm trying to modify my Advanced HTML/PDF template so that it hides all Inventory Items (Item lines) on invoices. I found SuiteAnswers 33495 and the following code snippet <#if !item.item?contains("Bed")>, but unable to get it to work with itemtype (tried to modify it to if !item.itemtype == "Inventory Item">). Can someone help me?

Snippet from SuiteAnswer:

```
...
</#if>
<#if !item.item?contains("Bed")>
<tr>
<td align="center" colspan="3" line-height="150%">${item.quantity}</td>
<td colspan="12"><span class="itemname"> ${item.item}</span><br 
/>${item.description}</td>
<td align="right" colspan="4">${item.rate}</td>
<td align="right" colspan="4">${item.amount} </td>
</tr>
</#if>
</#list> 
...
```

All I want to is to identify inventory items and hide them from the invoice and only display the serviceitem in invoice.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution would be filter the saved search to show Inventory only so you don't need to write any code to display in the Advanced HTML/PDF.

Comment: The problem with the code 
<#if ! item.itemtype == 'InvtPart'> is in the invoice 'item' part the 'itemtype' doesn't exist. To access such field you need to create a custom field for the invoice that sources this field from item.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `itemtype` for Inventory Items is `InvtPart`

```
<#if ! (item.itemtype == 'InvtPart')>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" colspan="3" line-height="150%">${item.quantity}</td>
    <td colspan="12"> <span class="itemname"> ${item.item}</span><br/> ${item.description} </td>
    <td align="right" colspan="4">${item.rate}</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="4">${item.amount} </td>
  </tr>
</#if>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion michoel! I tried that but i get this error: The template cannot be saved due to the following errors: 
     Error on line 217, column 8 in template
Expecting a boolean (true/false) expression here
Expression item.itemtype does not evaluate to true/false 
it is an instance of com.netledger.templates.model.StringModel

Comment: There's a typo there for sure (but I don't know if fixing that will be a working solution); should be: `<#if item.itemtype != 'InvtPart'>`.

Comment: @ddekany Whoops thanks for noticing, I've fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

One problem with your attempt is that `#if !item.itemtype == "Inventory Item"` means `#if (!item.itemtype) == "Inventory Item"`, that is, you try to "not" `item.itemtype` itself, which is not possible as that's not a boolean. You wanted `#if item.itemtype != "Inventory Item"`. Also @michoel says it's actually `"InvtPart"`, but I don't know that part (how exactly the data-model looks).

Answer (score 0):

could try this:

create custom transaction line level field called Item Type:

```
source list: item
source from: type
```

then in the HTML use

```
<#if !item.___(custom Item Type field id)____?contains("Inventory Item")>

(td item data)                   


</#if>
```